# selected option: this week, php

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown menu with this week and 6 other weeks.
this is my php code:

```
$Timestamp = strtotime('this week');
$output1 = [];
$output2 = [];
$output = [];

for ($week = 3; $week > 0; $week--)
{
$output1[] = date('W Y', strtotime(sprintf('-%d weeks', $week), 
$Timestamp));
}

for ($week = 0; $week < 4; $week++) 
{ 
$output2[] = date('W Y', strtotime(sprintf('+%d weeks', $week), 
$Timestamp));
}

$output = array_merge($output1, $output2);
```

And I have this html(php) code:

```
<select name="weeks">
<?php foreach ($output as $week) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $week ?>">
    <?php echo 'Week ' . $week ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This code above works perfect.

What I want is to give  the attribute 'selected'. so when i open up the page I see which week I have in front of me.
So this is what I have tried, I changed my html(php) code to:

```
<select name="weeks">
<?php foreach ($output as $week) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $week ?>"
    <?php 
    $weekToday = date('W');
    if ($week = $weekToday) 
    {
        echo 'selected';
    }
    ?>>
    <?php echo 'Week ' . $week ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

When I run this code, it  gives me the options to only select week 20 (this week). But the output of the values are good.
What did I do wrong and what do I need to change to have the right output?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
if ($week = $weekToday) 
{
    echo 'selected';
}
```

comparison can be done using `==` not `=`

Comment: That did work for the display, but it still doesn't select the this week

Comment: That's because the value of your options also includes the year and the variable `weekToday` does not: `$weekToday = date('W Y');`

Comment: @DarkBee good point

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfect!